# Horizontal Scroll bar appearing on website

Tags: html, css, joomla

There is a horizontal scroll bar appearing here on chrome:

[http://www.marketingagencyleeds.co.uk/](http://www.marketingagencyleeds.co.uk)

I am not quite sure what is causing this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, we appreciate your code being posted in your comment, even if it is on a website already. If the website goes down, this question instantly becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

---

It's appearing because your container widths are `1200px`, if your screen width is less then that... well you'll get a scroll bar.

If you want to hide the scroll bar, add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body` element

Comment: You're advertising web design and development, your container is overflowing (hence the scrollbar, body .rt-container), your aliases are wrong, you have plain-text emails and that's just what caught my eye in 30 secs. Hire someone here on stackoverflow to fix it for you.